# Rotate images as well as the description and link

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I would like to make some changes on a code and add some more options:

1- Rotate the images with the description of each one as well as the link,
2- Add the effect fadeOut while the image is disappearing.

Here is my little code:

```
var images = new Array ('BMW.png', 'Maybach.png', 'Mercedes-Benz.png', 'Mini.png', 'Jaguar.png', 'Toyota.png');
var descs = new Array ('BMW', 'Maybach', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'Mini', 'Jaguar', 'Toyota');
var links = new Array ('www.url1.com', 'www.url2.com', 'www.url3.com', 'www.url4.com', 'www.url5.com', 'www.url6.com');
var index = 1;

function rotateImage()
{
    $('#myImage').fadeOut('fast', function()
    {
        $(this).attr('src', images[index]);

        $(this).fadeIn(2000, function()
        {
            if (index == images.length-1)
            {
                index = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
            }
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    setInterval (rotateImage, 7000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
    <a href="www.url1.com">
        <img class="rotate" id="myImage" src="BMW.png" width="800" height="300" alt="image test" />
    </a>
    <div class="rotate" id="myDesc" style="margin-top: -30px; margin-left: 30px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you just use `new Array` to create a new array...

Answer (score 0):

uhm... something like this?

(Array is ZERO base so... initial index is 0 [with 1 you start with "Maybach.png" not "BMW.png" ]).

"Add the effect fadeOut while the image is disappearing" - if the image is disappearing is already doing a fade out... you should explain this point...

However...

```
var images = ['http://placehold.it/150x100', 'http://placehold.it/120x150', 'http://placehold.it/90x120', 'http://placehold.it/100x100', 'http://placehold.it/100x150', 'http://placehold.it/150x100'],
descs = ['BMW', 'Maybach', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'Mini', 'Jaguar', 'Toyota'],
links = ['www.url1.com', 'www.url2.com', 'www.url3.com', 'www.url4.com', 'www.url5.com', 'www.url6.com'],
index = 0; //start from first image
function rotateImage()
{
    $('#test').fadeOut('fast', function() //fadeout all block (if display none collapse your graphics use animate and "opacity") to hide without change display
    {
        $(this).find("a").attr('href', links[index]); //add href to url
        $(this).find("img").attr('src', images[index]); //add src to image
        $(this).find("#myDesc").text(descs[index]); //add description in desc div
        $(this).delay(500).fadeIn(2000, function() //delay (a little bit) to wait image load (for bigger image you need longer delay)
        {
            if (index == images.length-1)
            {
                index = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
            }
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    rotateImage(); //fire first time and then use Setinterval for loop
    setInterval (rotateImage, 7000);
});
```

[Example HERE jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/qkQR5/)

I hope this can help.

Simple image preload:

```
<img src="path/placeholder.gif" data-src="path/realImage.jpg" style="display:none" />
```

so the image that be loaded is a gif of trasparent singol pixel. when you need to preload you only need to place `data-src` in `src` and than show image... (do this when the prev image of your animation was displayed for prevent the load gap when this image will display)

Comment: it's a pleasure... but there are a lot of ways to done this work... checks your best one! - HTML-CSS-JS are powerful if used with head. Have FUN!

Comment: is right, mate! Maybe you can print all image in seuqnce and  avery time you change image preload the next one to prevent the "gap" from display to load. So you can remove `.delay(500)` because the image is already in the cacha and load instantly.

Comment: that's what I did, I removed the daly, it took more time to be displayed

Comment: Depends of image size... So check my answer above "Simple image preload:" ... duplicate this `<img class="rotate" id="myImage" src="BMW.png" width="800" height="300" alt="image test" />` (remind to remove id) and so... show ones and hide other. On the hide image add src of next image and on change hide the show image and vice versa. :)